# Selenium using xpath - How to get elements text using their sibling element text

Tags: html, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, gettext

I am stuck at one end, I am not able to get text value.

For better view :-

```
<div class="">
 <span class="address_city">Glenwood</span>
 <span class="address_state">GA</span>
 <span class="address_zip xh-highlight">30428</span>
</div>
```

I identify class `address_zip...` using following xpath :

```
//*[contains(text(),'30428')]
```

How can I get text value **GA** and **Glenwood**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `preceding-sibling`

```
//*[contains(text(),'30428')]/preceding-sibling::span[@class='address_city']
//*[contains(text(),'30428')]/preceding-sibling::span[@class='address_state']
```

You can also locate the zip code element and use it

```
WebElement zip = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'30428')]"));
String city = zip.findElement(By.xpath("//preceding-sibling::span[@class='address_city']")).getText();
String state = zip.findElement(By.xpath("//preceding-sibling::span[@class='address_state']")).getText();
```

Comment: Thanks , that what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

> It won't work , coz there is duplicate class name for same , Thats why I ask that is there any way to point from text() to upper two element.

You can use below `xpath` :-

- To get **Glenwood** text :

  ```
  .//div[span[text() = '30428']]/span[@class = 'address_city']
  ```
- To get **GA** text :

  ```
  .//div[span[text() = '30428']]/span[@class = 'address_state']
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Why do not you just use:

```
string city =Driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("address_city")).Text;
string state =Driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("address_state")).Text;
```

in case these classes are duplicated for other elements:

```
//first get the zip as you are doing now.
IWebElement zip=Driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//*[contains(text(),'30428')]"));

//now get the father element.
IWebElement father=zip.FindElement(By.XPath(".."));

//now get all the spans
IList<IWebElement> allElements=father.FindElements(By.TagName("span"));

//reach the elements you want.
IWebElement city=allElements.ElementAt(0);
IWebElement state=allElements.ElementAt(1);
```

Comment: It won't work , coz there is duplicate class name for same , Thats why I ask that is there any way to point from text() to upper two element.

Answer (score 0):

//*[contains(text(),'30428')]/preceding-sibling::span[contains(@class,'address_city')]
//*[contains(text(),'30428')]/preceding-sibling::span[contains(@class,'address_state')]

Answer (score 0):

Try these below mentioned `xpath`

Get value of **GA**

```
//span[text()= '30428']/..//preceding-sibling::span[text()= 'GA')]
```

**Explanation of xpath:-** Use `text` method along with `<span>` tag and move ahead with another `<span>` tag using `preceding-sibling keyword`.

> OR

```
//span[text()= 'Glenwood']/following-sibling::span[text()= 'GA']
```

**Explanation of xpath:-** Use `text` method along with `<span>` tag and move ahead with another `<span>` tag using `following-sibling keyword`.

> OR

```
//span[text()= 'Glenwood']/..//following-sibling::span[text()= 'GA']
```

**Explanation of xpath:-** Use `text` method along with `<span>` tag and move ahead with another `<span>` tag using `following-sibling keyword`.

Get value of **Glenwood**

```
//span[text()= 'GA']/..//preceding-sibling::span[text()= 'Glenwood']
```

**Explanation of xpath:-** Use `text` method along with `<span>` tag and move ahead with another `<span>` tag using `preceding-sibling keyword`.